# Javascript IDE that can tell me where the crash occured & let me inspect variable values at that point

Tags: javascript, debugging, ide

Can anyone suggest a Javascript IDE that will help me with debugging, for example be able to tell me which .js file & which function/line caused a crash?

I am currently using Notepad2 & its extremely difficult if not impossible to figure out why the app is crashing. Right now if I attempt to print out the object/variable causing the crash using...

```
alert(obj);
```

...It causes a crash. It is really frustrating because something weird is happening where just accessing the variable - ie passing the variable in a function as a parameter or alerting it - causes Firefox to have a catastrophic crash & Safari just has no failure output(I'm sure the error occurs but it recovers gracefully).

Ever experienced this kind of problem with Javascript before? Maybe you can say "I know what that is because its happened to me before, its x doing y"?

For example: "I know what that is because its happened to me before, your calling a prototype/object static function as a member function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet explorer have Console ( in IE 8 and IE 9 console is usable ) - press F12

Firefox have plugin named firebug

Chrome and Opera have built in consoles ( Press Ctrl + Shift + I )

All of them know what it is break point, can watch some variables etc.
Chrome speciality is break on event.
IE speciality is break on error, and recover from error.

All of them allows you to find out place where script crashes

Comment: Firebug is highly recommended and also Visual Studio 2010 if you have it.

Comment: my favorite is Chrome debug tools :-).But missing break on error and recovery after error in nonIE

Comment: @SergeS Chrome has "break on error." Scripts tab → pause symbol on the left. http://i.imgur.com/E6Fj4.png

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers come with a Javascript debugger. Safari/Chrome have the Script area in the Webkit Inspector. It allows you to set breakpoints, step through code and inspect variable states. Firefox has something similar in Firebug.